# Problem with not being able to access an id that is a child of the component from outside the component

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

My code is as below. It works when I create the videoOutput at the same level as the MediaPlayer and set the videoOutput id to the videoOutput variable of the MediaPlayer. But when I put VideoOutput in Component I can't access id in component from MediaPlayer. Since I will have more than one video source, I want to create multiple VideoOutput components, call them in different qmls and manage them both with a single MediaControlBar.

I tried property alias but still couldn't access it.

```
Item{
    id: kameraKaydi1
    property alias videoOutput : videoOutput

    Rectangle {
        id: kameraKaydi1Rectangle
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "#0b2a3e"

        VideoOutput {
            id: videoOutput
            property bool fullScreen: false

            anchors.fill: parent

            TapHandler {
                onDoubleTapped: {
                    parent.fullScreen ?  showNormal() : showFullScreen()
                    parent.fullScreen = !parent.fullScreen
                }
                onTapped: {
                    metadataInfo.visible = false
                    audioTracksInfo.visible = false
                    videoTracksInfo.visible = false
                    subtitleTracksInfo.visible = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

MediaPlayer {
    id: mediaPlayer
    source: "/../Assets/Videos/kokpit_video.mp4"
    function updateMetadata() {
        metadataInfo.clear();
        metadataInfo.read(mediaPlayer.metaData);
        metadataInfo.read(mediaPlayer.audioTracks[mediaPlayer.activeAudioTrack]);
        metadataInfo.read(mediaPlayer.videoTracks[mediaPlayer.activeVideoTrack]);
    }

    videoOutput: kameraKaydi1.videoOutput
    audioOutput: AudioOutput {
        id: audio
        muted: playbackControl.muted
        volume: playbackControl.volume
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you place your `property alias`?

Comment: @nomoresegmentationfaults I made videoOut the id instead of videoOutput and used it as "property alias videoOutput: videoOut" in the line with "//property variant videoOutput : videoOut".

Comment: You can safely use the same name for alias and id. Adding `property alias videoOutput : videoOutput` right below `id: kameraKaydi1Rectangle` should work. Then you can access it as `kameraKaydi1Rectangle.videoOutput`.

Comment: thanks for your advice, i updated the code like you said. But still it doesn't work. I also updated the code in my post. You can see the updated code above. @nomoresegmentationfaults

Comment: My mistake, I thought MediaPlayer was within Component's scope. You have to place alias under `id: kameraKaydi1` not `id: kameraKaydi1Rectangle`.

Comment: @nomoresegmentationfaults i tried before, when i try that, i take warning, Component objects cannot declare new properties.

Comment: I don't know if it causes any problem, but you can use `Item` instead of `Component`

Comment: @nomoresegmentationfaults It worked with Item instead of Component. I uptaded code in post. I will check what is the different between Component and Item.Thank you :)

Comment: Item is an instance, Component is an item definition. you cannot access component's content because it's not exist.

Comment: Using an Item will not work when you have multiple videoOutput as you state in the question, you will need to use multiple Loader with the Component and then reference the property like loader1.item.videoOutput (and put the alias on the Rectangle level)

Comment: @Amfasis actually I created stackviews in 2 different qml and used 2 different items in main as these stackviews initial item. This way it worked flawlessly. I have defined two separate mediaPlayers as required in the qml of the controller in the main and I can make settings such as video time, speed and volume with a single controller.

Now everything works as I want. I think what you suggest is similar to what I did.